# how to build a regular expression (regex) for slangs and emoticons

Tags: java, regex

i need to build a regex to match slangs (i.e. lol, lmao, imo, etc..) and emoticons (i.e. :), :P, ;), etc...).

i followed the example at http://www.coderanch.com/t/497238/java/java/Regular-Expression-Detecting-Emoticons. however, this method/approach is failing for me.

for example, let's say i need to match the slang "od". i create a Pattern as follows.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("od"));

let's say i need to match the slang "od" in the following test sentence, "some methods are bad." empirically, there is one match on the word "methods" in the string, which is not what i want.

i did read some of the javadoc and some of the tutorial regarding java and regex, but i still can't figure this out.

by the way, i am using Java 6 (though i've looked and reference the java 5 api doc).

if regex is not the best way to go, i am opened to other solutions as well. thanks in advance for any help/pointers. the following code gets me 3 matches and is based on the link above.

```
String regex = "od";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(regex));
String str = "some methods are bad od od more text";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

the following code returns no matches and is based on the responses so far.

```
String regex = "\bod\b";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
//Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(regex)); //this fails
String str = "some methods are bad od od more text";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

after the two helpful responses below, i will post the correct/desired code snippet here.

```
String regex = "(\\bod\\b)|(\\blmao\\b)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
String str = "some methods are bad od od more text lmao more text";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

this code is correct or as desired because empirically, it gives me 3 matches (2 od and 1 lmao). sorry, i wish i am stronger with regex using java (and just regex in general). thanks for your help.

Comment: Only match the emoticons if they're followed and preceeded by a space, punctuation, beginning of line or end of line.

Comment: do i have to pass this regex through Pattern.quote(String str)?

Answer (score 2):

[:;]-?[DP()]

handles the combinations of ":" or ":" plus either "-" and "D" or "P" or ")" or "("

eg. :P :-( ;D etc...

just add more combinations...

have fun..

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundaries (`\b`) in order to match a word that's *just* the slang you want.

So for example, the pattern `"\bod\b"` will match "od", but won't match "method".

Comment: How does it "fail"? And how are you inputting these? If it's directly in your Java code then you'll need to escape the backslashes again - `"\\bod\\b"` (if you don't, Java will think it's a backspace character instead of a backslash followed by a b)

Comment: ok, you are right. thanks. the regex is directly in my java code. in method two above, after modifying it to String regex = "\\bod\\b", then it works. i would vote both of you, but i can't since i'm a n00b, pun intended. let me add the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use a regex?  I would do

```
String str = "some methods are bad od od more text lmao more text";
String[] words = str.split(" ");
for (String s : words) {
  if (s.equals("od") || s.equals("lamo"))
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use more metacharacters and class of characters in the Regular Expression.
[Oracle Regular Expressions Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html)
You can head here if you want to know about metacharacters and their different combinations.