# Detecting emoticons with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a class to detect emoticons and have the following to detect `:)` smilies including their various variations (`=], =), [=, [:,` etc.), but it doesn't work and I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong. I'm testing it in JSFiddle.

```
var DetectEmoticons = {
    countHappy: function(data) {
        var pattern = new RegExp("[:/=]-?[]/)] | [[/(]-?[:/=]", "g");
        var count = (data.match(pattern) || []).length;
        return count;
    }
}
alert(DetectEmoticons.countHappy("=)"));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425683/how-to-build-a-regular-expression-regex-for-slangs-and-emoticons?rq=1 should help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[:=;]-?[)(|\\/\]\[]|[)(|\\/\]\[]-?[:=;]`

This looks like an unholy mess from hell until you break it down:

`[:=;]` matches one : or one = or one ;

`[)(|\\/\]\[]` matches one ), (, |, \ (backslashed because it is a metacharacter), /, ] (backslashed because it is a metacharacter) or [ (backslashed because it is a metacharacter). (We didn't need to backslash ) or ( because they are not metacharacters inside of a character class).

The `|` in the center means 'match left of me OR match right of me' and then I write the same two character classes but in reverse to match smileys that are reversed in direction.

I think the problem with your regex is here:

`[]/)]`

You forgot to escape the first `]` with a `\` so it is treated as ending the character class prematurely.

The other problem is that you thought forward slash `/` is used to escape. It's not, `\` is used to escape, `/` has no special meaning in regex.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but how come it still doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/TTWsa/

Comment: You need double the backslashes, i.e. ``\\`` becomes ``\\\\``, and ``\`` becomes ``\\``.  This is because of both string and RegExp escaping.

Comment: @ibopm Do you have to double up backslashes?

Comment: If it's going to be static, you can also use a RegExp literal instead of `new RegExp()`, and avoid the backslash issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/TTWsa/2/