# How to change a specific content with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add emotions to my blog. When I write ":)" on a post, it should change into an image automatically. But I don't know how to do it.

The real problem is, I don't know how to identify all ":)" emotions. I can do the rest, if I do that. So, anyone can help me?

Comment: I think you mean **emoticons**.

Comment: Add some emotions to your site by putting naked ladies in there

Comment: Any piece of code you tried and fail? What google say? What SO say? google for `javascript emoticon detection` and you can find a lot of answer even here in SO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting emoticons with regex in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954047/detecting-emoticons-with-regex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking out **:contains()** selector.

```
$(".article:containts(':)')")
```

After that, you can store the text in a variable, manipulate it (find & replace), replace the text with an image, and overwrite the element's html with the new manipulated html.

https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: This is what I was looking for actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try google: https://os.alfajango.com/css-emoticons/

Never used it but looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I have googled your query and found some helpful libraries. Please find link below:

http://hassankhan.me/emojify.js/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoticons-js

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery selectors to select all elements which are conatining ':)' then try to cut it and replace it with some emotion icon.

```
$('p:contains(\':)\')')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code:

```
<div id="post_1" class="post">
   Nice to meet you :) Bye bye!
</div>
```

You can replace the emoticon using [.indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) and [.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) combined.

```
var contentReplaced = $("#post_1").html().toString().replace(":)", "<img src='path_to_image' />");
$("#post_1").html(contentReplaced);
```